# Show all data in database table and make it into an interactive table

Tags: wp-query, menus, database, table

I have to make a table where my data from my database can be stored and rearranged with every row.
The name of every row should be a link to the function `mymanual_edit()`.

Look at the image for reference.

This is my database `wp_mymanual()`:

```
`wp_mymanual` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `description` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  `producer` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `version` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `versiondateday` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `versiondatemonth` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `versiondateyear` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `validafterday` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `validaftermonth` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `validafteryear` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `validuntilday` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `validuntilmonth` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `validuntilyear` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `subtype` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `visible` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `file` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `filetype` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
)
```

[image]

Comment: And the question is.. _*drum roll*_ How to make rows sortable? How to make row title a link? Make front-end table with WordPress list of posts functionalities? Did I get one of these right? Format of this and many similar websites requires you to ask one question at a time with corresponding title so that it's easily answerable and searchable.

Comment: Actually, never mind... I created something better...
But yeah, my questions were as follows:
1. How do I create tables?
2. How do I fill them with info?
3. Are the colums sortable per default?